# Does HTML and CSS needs to be valid before we apply JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was thinking about Web standards, and i was wondering if we need to have valid HTML and CSS before we apply JavaScript?

Can anyone enlighten me on the relation between valid HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

For instance, does invalid HTML and CSS prevent JavaScript from working correctly?

Comment: Always remember your most serious website users will be using Firefox with the NoScript extension. Thus you must make sure your website is fully functional without javascript. Javascript should only be used to enhance user experience.

Comment: @PP: this advice is ridiculous. Your site should be fully functional without js to appease google and the other bots, not to satisfy J. Random Nerd with NoScript. The percentage of surfers using noscript is still negligible for almost all sites (if you do have statistics, please cite).

Comment: The answer to the first question is opinion-based; the answer to the second question is too broad, and the answer to the third question can be found trivially by running your code yourself in a couple of minutes. Since there are three separate questions here, this is also too broad.

Comment: @TylerH — The third part can't be trivially tested that way since *some* invalid code will break *some* JS.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, I have clarified my comment above.

Answer (score 4):

As much lip service as we pay to having valid HTML, browsers are extremely forgiving. The reasons for this are historical. There was (and still is) a lot of bad HTML in the beginning.

But you may get unpredictable differences between browsers with badly formed HTML. For example, different browsers may treat an unclosed tag differently.

All the markup causes to happen is to form a DOM (Document Object Model) in the browser based on how that browser interpreted it. CSS and Javascript are both applied to the DOM.

Comment: They're forgiving ... until they're not. At my last job we had to run our social media pages in harmony with client HTML, CSS and Javascript. And let me tell you, some of that stuff didn't play nice at all. You find out that certain browsers ignore unbalanced elements, incorrectly self-closed elements, etc., and some don't. The absolute worst mess to clean up was someone's poorly nested tables. Or (true story) someone who put DIV elements around all his TR elements "for the extra CSS class" that would give him.

Comment: Sadly, I must agree.  "Valid" HTML in terms of 100% W3C Compliant is a bit of overkill.  

Certainly all you tags must be closed, and being conistent with best practces is always good, but I've never had javascript fail on me because I missed "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
"
Heh.

Comment: hi thank you for your response. Does that mean the DOCTYPE, or XHTML, or HTML does not really affects how JavaScript works?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396683/does-html-and-css-needs-to-be-valid-before-we-apply-javascript/2396705#2396705) [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396683/does-html-and-css-needs-to-be-valid-before-we-apply-javascript/2396701#2396701): I have had very bad times hunting through apparent javascript bugs before I remembered to [validate](http://validator.w3.org) the page I was working on. As soon as I corrected the glaring errors, the scripts worked as intended.

The most obvious problem (not one I have experienced, because I already look for that): have two elements with the same id attribute, and try to make your script that depends on that to work as intended :)

While it may be true that the level of validation needed is somewhat low, when you are banging your head against the table because your website doesn't work and you don't know why, you'll remember this fondly.

Comment: While I don't disagree with @cletus, I do agree with your broad point. But that seems to be the point that cletus hints at: JS/CSS operates on the DOM, html forms the basis of the DOM. So if the DOM is badly-formed -from invalid (x)html- then js/css will not necessarily work (or work as intended). I'd up-vote, but I'm already out of votes for the day. =/

Comment: well, if the question is "do negligible html / css errors stop js from working", then cletus is right. Though CSS errors can be quite unforgiving. But in the general case, it's not. It's far cheaper and easier to check your html and CSS for validity. It's cheaper yet (but harder) to build valid html and css. I'm not talking about zealot levels of validity, but about ensuring that the DOM tree is valid and that there are no css errors.